# Sharepoint 365 allowing me to only write two items then stops responding

Tags: c#, json, sharepoint

Background; it was working with SP2013, but a supplier has switched to SP365.

Modifying the authentication using OfficeDevPnP.Core.AuthenticationManager, ClientID and ClientSecret I can get the access token. I can then do all the JSON reads I like, but it will only allow me to write two items to a list (orders), then it just times out. I restart the project and it does exactly the same. I can read the list to make sure the order hasn't been uploaded already, but when it comes to writing the third item it just throws timeout errors.

I updated the code to call for a new access token for each write and just get "Token Request Failed" after the second write.

Any thoughts on how to approach the supplier on config options, or change my approach?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, changing up the usage of GetAppOnlyAuthenticatedContext to something like this works wonders.

```
    public void CreateListItemV2(string listName, QDS_WorkOrderEntry entry)
    {
        OfficeDevPnP.Core.AuthenticationManager authMgr = new OfficeDevPnP.Core.AuthenticationManager();

        using (var context = authMgr.GetAppOnlyAuthenticatedContext(SPSiteUrl, "<clientid>", "<secret>"))
        {
            List list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listName);

            var itemCreateInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();
            var newItem = list.AddItem(itemCreateInfo);
            newItem["HHSDetails"] = entry.HHSDetails?.HHSDetailsId;
            ...
            newItem.Update();

            context.Load(newItem);
            context.ExecuteQuery();
        }
    }
```